# Making three Card on Jetpack Compose, but only two are shown

Tags: android, android-cardview, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-card

I try to build three different class cards. But why only two is shown?

[image: Preview]

Code:

```
   Scaffold(....){
    innerPadding ->
            BodyContent(Modifier.padding(innerPadding).fillMaxWidth())
        Card(shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(16.dp)) {
                Text("Card COntent")
            }
            Card(backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.surface, shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium,
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                Text("Card COntent")
            }
            Card(Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(16.dp), elevation = 8.dp   ) {
                Text("Card COntent")
            }
    }
```

Comment: The first card is below the third card, so it's not visible. it's like FrameLayout, if you want to achieve more, try to use Row or Column or any other compose layout and add the cards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is your screen:

[image]

The first card is covered by the third card.

Use something like:

```
   Column() {
        Card() {..}
        Card() {..}
        Card() {..}
    }
```

[image]